# Windows 7 "Save as" dialog waking up all HDDs

Tags: windows, hard-drive, mount, sleep

1. My OS is running from SSD.
2. Recently I've moved my often used data also onto SSD to avoid unnecessary spinning and noise of my other standard HDD.
3. This HDD is put to sleeping mode after 10 minutes of inactivity.

**Therefore:** This HDD should sleep (not spinning) almost all the time, since I am primarily using SSD.

However it won't because almost every Save as dialog (Chrome etc.) touches every available drive even though I'm not going to save there anything nor browsing it.

I don't want to shorten the period from 10 to something like 1 minute. It would partially solve the issue but my HDD would spin-up many times a day which would most likely noticeably shorten its lifespan.

Changing Windows native behaviour of Save as dialog might not be possible, also some apps using their own. Physically unplug HDD isn't good idea either since I need to access that HDD several times a week.

So, if I'm not mistaken, this would cut my question to this: **What is the most easier and reliable way to UNMOUT / MOUNT HDD under Windows 7? Preferably without using 3rd party apps.** I hate the idea of clicking some icon before and after every access to HDD but I can't think of anything else.

Answer (score 0):

If your drives are set to AHCI in the BIOS, then you can dismount them just like a USB drive. However, you will need to restart to get the dismounted drives back.

Comment: That would be actually nice way to do it, but restart makes it almost unusable. It would be too annoying closing all my work for restart to access my data.

Comment: As much as I wish there a solution (I have similar annoyances with terribly slow WD Green drives), I don't think there is one unless your motherboard supports hot-swapping drives.

Comment: You should be able to scan for hardware changes and get it back. Maybe use diskpart and do a rescan. Or you might be able to use diskpart to set the drive offline instead of removing it.

Comment: Now I've reliazed that even with [diskpart; select disk 1; offline/online disk] command, HDD is still getting woken up at some situation I can't prevent. Like launching some apps. Still, it's better than nothing. Windows almost all the time does something to make the HDD "grunt". Now it's just spinning at least.